# SQL Server Bulk Insert with "^M" rowterminator

Tags: sql, import, bulk

I have a flat file that ends each row with a ^M character. I have found that this is generated from dos/windows OS and is a visual representation of 0x0D. I am trying to do a bulk insert on the file into SQL Server 2008 but I can't find a way to define ^M in a way that the process will know it is the rowterminator. I have tried specifying it multiple ways but no success. Any ideas on how to import this file with the "^M" character as the rowterminator?

Answer (score 0):

`dos2unix fileNameCreatedInWindows.sql` this small utility should help.

It does what it says, converts Windows specific delimiters into Unix delimiters. Then you can use this file to perform bulk insert.

Comment: I looked at dos2unix but at this moment I wanted to see if it is possible to not modify the file and still have it import with the special character. This is going to be a daily cron job that will be locked down in a Windows OS environment. So unix commands will not be available at this time.

Comment: if it's a cron job, you can have a shell script that (1)converts the file into Unix like, (2)performs whatever action you do with this file, (3) deletes the files -- now ask cron to run that script. I do not see what issue is.

Comment: I am sorry, when i say cron job I meant Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: same process, do in windows use something liek this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=760796

Answer (score 0):

0x0D is \r; have you tried passing in a \r\n rowterminator parameter to the bulk insert command?

Comment: Thanks, when I try "\n" or "\r\n" it reads the whole file as one row and doesn't import anything. However, if I put "\r" I get the error "Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file."